# tikz - Multiple nodes with same content

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

I would like to know how to place multiple nodes with same content in TikZ.

I've made a macro for it, but I think that it could have a different approach.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\cross}{%
    node {\LARGE\bm{$\times$}}%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black]
    (1,1) \cross
    (3,1) \cross
    (1,4) \cross
    (3,4) \cross;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So, my question is: is there any way to do something like this?

```
\cross{(1,1), (3,1), (1,4), (3,4)}
```

Comment: @GutierrezPS, you can use a loop: `\foreach \p in {(1,1),(3,1),(1,4),(3,4)}{\draw \p node {\LARGE\bm{$\times$}};}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out that [Sigur](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14757/sigur)'s solution was exactly what I wanted (I just needed to put in a macro). So, instead of

```
\newcommand{\contact}{ node {\LARGE\bm{$\times$}} }
```

I've used

```
\newcommand{\contacts}[1]{ %
    \foreach \p in {#1}{\p node {\LARGE\bm{$\times$}}} %
}
```

In this case, `\contacts` should be used inside a `\draw` block:

```
\draw \contacts((1,1),(5,1),(1,4),(3,1),(5,4));
```

That produces something like:

[image]